# Kotlin ViewModel is not updating when there are changes in Firebase Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a ViewModel that accesses the database (Firebase) and counts documents. The structure of the database is this: Collection "Posts" --> Document --> Collection "Likes" --> Documents.
So I access the collection "Posts" and then for each document that contains my username, I access the collection "Likes" and get the snapshot size to count how many likes are there. The problem is that when a new Like document is created the ViewModel won't get the updates until the app is restarted.

**The way I am using the ViewModel:**
I have a navigation graph and that's where I create an instance of the ViewModel, then I call the function that retrieves the data and then I pass this instance as an argument in the other screen where I need the data. In the other screen, I access the variable where the data is stored. The variable where data is stored in a StateFlow (because I pass here the counter value not the documents)

**Code (ViewModel):**

```
class PointsViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val firebase = Firebase.firestore
    private var _points = MutableStateFlow(0)
    val points: StateFlow<Int> = _points

    fun calculate(username: String){
        firebase.collection("Posts")
            .whereEqualTo("PostUser",username)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { posts ->
                for(post in posts){
                    post.reference.collection("Likes").get().addOnSuccessListener { likes ->
                        _points.value += likes.size()
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

**Code (Where I create instance in NavGraph):**

```
val pointsViewModel: PointsViewModel = viewModel()

//sharedViewModel contains the username
sharedViewModel.user?.username?.let { pointsViewModel.calculate(it) }
```

**Code (Where I need the data):**

```
fun AwardsScreen(sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel,pointsViewModel: PointsViewModel){
    
    val points by pointsViewModel.points.collectAsState()
    

    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(15.dp, 15.dp)) {


        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
           Text(text = points.toString())
        }
    }
```

I tried to do all these operations inside the screen I need the data. So I tried to access the database and retrieve all data from there, adding a snapshotListener to get the updates but it didn't work

Comment: Did ZooS's answer solve your problem?

Comment: No not yet. I replied to his comment explaining what's not working

Comment: To understand better, do you need a real-time counter?

Comment: Yes. So I need a counter that updates every time there is a change in database. I tried a snapshot listener and it does listen to changes, the problem is as I explained to ZooS, that every time a document is added or deleted in the database the counter will increment. That's because it maintains the previous counter and then recounts documents, adding the new number of documents. So if I have 3 documents the counter will be 3 and when I delete 1 document the counter will recount the documents and add the new value to the previous value, so 3+2

Comment: Aside from my answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-count-the-number-of-documents-in-a-firestore-collection-3bd0c719978f) will also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how you should do when it comes to counters in Firestore. When you count documents as you do now, it will cost you one read for each document your query returns, and this can be expensive when it comes to a larger number of likes. Unfortunately, [count()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries#use_the_count_aggregation) doesn't provide real-time updates. However, it will be less expensive if you create and maintain a counter yourself. That can simply be a field of type number that exists in a document. This means that each time a new document is added to a collection you can simply [increment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value) the counter, and decrement it when a document is deleted. On this document, you can attach a real-time listener and you'll have a counter that is always up to date. This means that in order to display the number of likes, you'll only need to pay for a single read.

Such operations should not be performed in the client-side code but in a trusted environment. So I recommend you write a function in [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) that does that automatically for you.

Comment: I thought of this as a last resort  because i have to modify everything now

Comment: That's right, but in the long term, it will be much cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

First, just a small nitpick, the `_points` can be `val` and actually should be since you do not want to change the actual instance, just its value.

The other thing I noticed is that you are using the `+=` operand which might be the culprit here. Try assigning a new value like `_points.value = _points.value + likes.size()`.

The [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#augmented-assignments) say

> For the assignment operations, for example a += b, the compiler
> performs the following steps:
>
> If the function from the right column is available:
>
> If the corresponding binary function (that means plus() for
> plusAssign()) is available too, a is a mutable variable, and the
> return type of plus is a subtype of the type of a, report an error
> (ambiguity).
>
> Make sure its return type is Unit, and report an error otherwise.
>
> Generate code for a.plusAssign(b).
>
> Otherwise, try to generate code for a = a + b (this includes a type
> check: the type of a + b must be a subtype of a).

It might need a completely new value without referencing itself in the assignment.

And in the end, I would recommend using a state holder. So you would have a class like this:

```
data class StateHolder(val points: Int = 0)
```

And you would use it in the `viewModel` like so:

```
class PointsViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val firebase = Firebase.firestore
    private val _stateHolder = MutableStateFlow(StateHolder())
    val stateHolder: StateFlow<StateHolder> = _stateHolder

    fun calculate(username: String){
        firebase.collection("Posts")
            .whereEqualTo("PostUser",username)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { posts ->
                for(post in posts){
                    post.reference.collection("Likes")
                        .get()
                        .addOnSuccessListener { likes ->
                            _stateHolder.value = stateHolder
                                .value
                                .copy(points =  
                                    stateHolder.value.points + likes.size())
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

And finally, to observe it in a composable:

```
val stateHolder by pointsViewModel.stateHolder.collectAsState()
    

    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(15.dp, 15.dp)) {


        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), 
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
           Text(text = "${stateHolder.points}")
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works but when there are changes in the database the points won't update

Comment: I modified your code adding a snapshotListener. Now it listens to the changes because I can see the values update. The problem now is that "points" variable will only increment. I notice that when points = 3 and I add a new like in the database, points will become 7.  I guess that's because it is saving the previous number of likes and when there is a change it recounts everything adding the new value to the old value

Comment: Yeah, just change the logic then to reflect the actual value from the db and don't add the previous value. You should have only one source of truth and adding likes here will skew the actual value. I would recommend you calculate and add likes on the db side, when a new like comes just increment it in the db